# Drag to resize canvas size in GIMP the way I do it in MSPaint?

Tags: gimp

Any time I prefer Microsoft Paint over GIMP it's because in Paint you can simply and swiftly drag the canvas borders to enlarge it or crop it. I cannot understand why this feature is lacking in other editors.

Is it maybe somehow hidden? Can I do it in gimp?

Comment: This is the kind of question which might be a good fit for the proposed Graphic Design Software Support stack. Please see the proposal and follow it if you think it might be useful. You can also add this question as a sample. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86994/graphic-design-software-support/

Comment: As for this "Graphic Design Software Support" stack - where do I vote _against_ it? Butter can only be spread so thin, if you get me.
I instead invite advanced users for other software are not willing to answer one of each FAQ (however simple) here, and redirect duplicates there. I can do so for GIMP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Changing canvas size in Gimp

In Gimp we can use the *Crop* tool [image] (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) to quickly drag the canvas to a new size.

To allow growing as well as crop we need to check *Allow growing* in the toolbox as shown below.

1. **Draw a box for the new size**

   [image]

   The exact geometry of the new image will be shown in the bottom line while dragging.
2. **Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply**

   [image]

   The new background will be filled with the background colour as soon as we flatten the image to integrate the previous image's layer.
3. Click Image / Fix Canvas to Layers if you see "This active layer's pixels are locked" and the background matches the Gimp GUI.

Comment: Exactly what I want and even better than mspaint, allowing to grow/shrink in all 4 directions.

Comment: Hah.. I ahd even forgot about the "grow" feature of the crop tool - and was about to answer the requested ability  was not possible in GIMP. +1