# How to scale the alpha layer without scaling the image ? gimp

Tags: gimp, layers, transparency, scale

I am trying to write text which larger than the image itself, as you can see in the bellow picture:
[image]

but gimp doesn't show the complete text, because the alpha layer is smaller than the text size. How to scale the united states flag alpha layer without scaling the image itself ?
thanks

Comment: You can also use the crop/allow growing tool: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53502/drag-to-resize-canvas-size-in-gimp-the-way-i-do-it-in-mspaint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, it's not the alpha channel that is the problem.

The real problem is simply that you have created a text layer which is larger than your current **canvas size** and GIMP will only show that part which **is** visible within the canvas.

Just do *Image > Fit Canvas to Layers* to automatically re-size the canvas large enough to include your text layer, or *Image > Canvas Size..* to set the overall image size to specified dimensions.

ref: https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-resize.html