# Rotate layer with Gimp

Tags: gimp, rotate

I select the rotate tool and click a layer that contains an image.
I see a selection around the image. Not sure why and how to remove it.
I rotate the layer.
The rotated image is clipped against the selection, which means the rotated corners are cut off.

How do I rotate a layer without having it clipped against the selection?

I've tried all the different 'clipping' values in the tools menu. They all end up cropping the rotated image.

Comment: You may have to [increase the canvas size](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/53517/12941) to hold the rotated image.

Answer (score 8):

Do this:

Use the rotate tool. The canvas clips the image. But the image is now bigger than the canvas - the yellow dotted line shows the layer boundary.

Click Image > Fit Canvas to Layers, and the canvas expands to fit the rotated layer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `Clipping: adjust`. **However** this resizes the layer but not the canvas, so if you start with a layer which is as big as the canvas, you may also need to use `Image>Fit canvas to layers`.

Unlike the paint tools, the Transform tools do not behave the same with a full selection or with no selection. To remove the selection, use `Select>None`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I ran into this issue as well and for me doing a Select->None allowed the layer to rotate without clipping.  Gimp looks to have auto-resized the layer with nothing selected.

Comment: For me (GIMP version 2.8.2), said "Select->None" option is greyed out...